# Where is GNOME device configuration? - Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, input-devices, wayland, mutter

I recently install Ubuntu 17.10 on my Dell XPS 13 9365.  With GNOME Shell, from what I understand, Mutter is the default compositor, which supports the Wayland protocol.  I haven't been able to find related configuration for input devices.  I'd like to customize how touchpad and touchscreen work, and related questions seem to point to editing files in `xorg.conf.d`, which have no affect unless you start a session using "Ubuntu on Xorg" option.

Can anyone say where the configuration for Mutter/Wayland reside?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, Wayland does configuration a bit differently. I think to answer your question: the location you're interested in is `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. That should get you started (it did for me). Otherwise, yell out and we can sort out any additional config issues.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I hinted at this in my original post.  Making changes there takes no affect when using Wayland.  Specifically editing `40-libinput.conf` in that directory has no affect when using Wayland.  It does have an effect if I switch to x11 (changed using the gear icon on the login screen).  It seems like configuration of Wayland must happen elsewhere...

Comment: @JohnHalbert, thanks for keeping me honest. I could've sworn I've been making my edits there. Dang! I'll have to double-check if I'm running X or Wayland now...

Comment: @JohnHalbert, indeed, this has become an interesting question since moving to 17.10 (where Wayland is now default, hence my initial confusion). [Here's a good read to perhaps answer some aspect of your question](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/faq.html#faq_config_options), though it's a bit disconcerting.